# What is the inverse of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -I \\ I & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$I$ is the identity matrix. As mentioned above, I am trying to find the inverse of such a matrix - if it is possible?

A first attempt is to use Cramer's rule, which yields

$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{I} \\ -\frac{1}{I} & 0 \end{pmatrix} $

I am wonder what even the reciprocal of a (whole) matrix means..

Any guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Reciprocal is synonymous with (multiplicative) inverse. The only difference is that writing $\frac AB$ for matrices doesn't make sense because $A\frac1B$ and $\frac1BA$ might be different. Thus we prefer using $AB^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}A$ to make the order clear, and preventing people from using intuition for fractions that is invalid for matrices. For the same reason (non-commuting of matrix multiplication) you should be careful applying matrix rules (like Cramer's) to block matrices.

Comment: The notation of $\frac{A}{B}$ where $A,B$ are matrices is extremely common in physics though. And the above matrix is also quite common in physics as the Gram matrix of the symplectic innter product (on the phase space). it is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Since the inverse of $I$ is just $I,$ I think you can hence get
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{I} \\ -\frac{1}{I} & 0 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I \\ -I & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$,
which can be check is the inverse by multiplication.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I did not mean to write 'the inverse of $I$' using $\frac{1}{I}$ - I got the 'factor' of $\frac{1}{I}$ by applying Cramer's rule, where $\frac{1}{det(matrix)} = \frac{1}{I^2}$.